# MySQL select with multiple order by

Tags: mysql

So i got this table:

```
+----+---------------------+-----+----------------+
| ID | WHEN                | OFF | (other..stuff) |
+----+---------------------+-----+----------------+
| 1  | 2012-09-17 17:00:00 | 0   | anything1      |
| 2  | 2012-09-17 18:00:00 | 0   | anything2      |
| 3  | 2012-08-31 21:00:00 | 1   | blabla321      |
| 4  | 2012-08-31 18:30:00 | 1   | blab32121      |
+----+---------------------+-----+----------------+
```

I want to select all keys but:

- Keys with off = 0 should be order by when ASC, and they should be
  displayed first
- Keys with off = 1 should be order by when DESC, and they should be
  displayed after (at the end)

I tried something like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `off` = 0 ORDER BY `when` ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `off` = 1 ORDER BY `when` DESC)
```

But it doesn't work.

Also check:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWBEr.jpg

Comment: there is no error it just order everthing by `when` ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from `table`
order by `off`,
    case `off`
        when 0 then timestampdiff(second, current_timestamp, `when`)
        when 1 then timestampdiff(second, `when`, current_timestamp)
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE off = 0 ORDER BY `when` ASC) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE off = 1 ORDER BY `when` DESC);
```

I think WHEN is a keyword and must be quoted.

Comment: There is an `order by` on the first query. I just checked, it works fine.

Comment: I tried this, its almost ok. But the part with off = 1 is ordered the same as off = 0

Comment: that's weird, what's the type of the `when` column?

Comment: I saw that link on sqlfiddle and i think its good in there, but when i try to put that in phpmyadmin, it doesn't order it like that. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN off = 0 THEN `when` END ASC,
         CASE WHEN off = 1 THEN `when` END DESC
```

Comment: Its almost ok, but it shows first rows with off = 1, than at the end of table rows with off = 0. I tried to modify it but still, can't do that...